# How to (push) parse XML files in Python?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I've already seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1912434/3127111), but it's from the 2009.
What's a simple modern way to handle XML files in Python 3?

I.e., from this TLD (adapted from [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPTags6.html#wp90267)):

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib>
  <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
  <short-name>bar-baz</short-name>

  <tag>
  <name>present</name>
     <tag-class>condpkg.IfSimpleTag</tag-class>
  <body-content>scriptless</body-content>

  <attribute>
    <name>test</name>
    <required>true</required>
    <rtexprvalue>true</rtexprvalue>
  </attribute>

  </tag> 

</taglib>
```

I want to parse TLD files (Java Server Pages Tag Library Descriptors), to obtain some sort of structure in Python (I have still to decide about that part).

Hence, I need a push parser. But I won't do much more with it, so I'd rather prefer a simple API (I'm new to Python).

Comment: What is your desired output? What data do you need to get from the XML?

Comment: @alecxe I'm thinking about providing informations for an autocomplete feature of an editor, but I have yet to analyze the problem and understand that editor features; anyway I think that my effort should be data structure independent, so that, if one day I need to provide the parsed info to another piece of software, I'll just change the holding data structure, but not the parsing logic. But, as I said, everything is still at the beginning, so any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0):

[`xml.etree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) is still there, in the standard library:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

data = """your xml here"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print(tree.find('tag/name').text)  # prints "present"
```

---

If you look outside of the standard library, there is a very popular and fast [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/) module that follows the `ElementTree` interface and supports Python3:

```
from lxml import etree as ET

data = """your xml here"""

tree = ET.fromstring(data)
print(tree.find('tag/name').text)  # prints "present"
```

Besides, there is [`lxml.objectify`](http://lxml.de/objectify.html) that allows you to deal with XML structure like with a Python object.

Comment: I was thinking more to something like providing the XML file, a callback and the parser would invoke the callback providing each node context.

Comment: @watery hm, then I think you would find [`iterparse()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.iterparse) helpful. Take a look at the relevant threads: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9856163/using-lxml-and-iterparse-to-parse-a-big-1gb-xml-file, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12792998/elementtree-iterparse-strategy. Hope that helps.

Comment: I moved away from that project pretty soon, I hadn't had a chance to give this a try.